# brokerage bank accounts

Tags: brokerage

Can you have two bank accounts from two different countries with the same brokers company. ie buy sterling using a british account and cash it out in America with an american account with a view to not paying commission.

Comment: I don't see why not, but you would have to pay a fee for exchanging currency. i.e. you have two accounts with two separate amounts, 5 USD and 20,000 GBP but you can't withdraw the 20,000 GBP in America without first exchanging it into USD (and paying an exchange fee)

Comment: thank you, is the exchange fee lower than banks, their exchange rate seams to be higher than the markets and then they add commission also

Comment: I don't know of anywhere that you will get market rates. All banks I have seen have processing fees, and from what I understand all forex platforms have fees too. So I think what you're looking for doesn't exist, or it's readily available to the average person.

Comment: When cashing out, will it be in USD or GBP?

Comment: Do you have an examle for such a broker? The broker may have the same name in both countries, still, these may be two distinct companies.

Answer (score 0):

You raise 3 issues: multiple bank accounts, accounts with different currencies, and fees.

Bank accounts are all separate. Even if you have two accounts with a single bank in one country, both linked to your broker via direct debit / direct credit arrangements, each account has its own balance and it’s own transaction history. You can use sweep arrangements and the like to automatically move funds from one account to another, but that’s not the same as depositing in one account and withdrawing those funds from another.

Banks always segregate currencies. Even if they say you have a single account with multiple currencies in it, they will report how much you hold of each currency separately. The closest that I’ve seen to being able to deposit and withdraw in different currencies in different countries are travel cards that allow you to load multiple currencies - if you run out of a currency, it can automatically draw from another currency within the account and do the conversion automatically. But even there, each currency is reported separately, and I’d expect that the FX conversions would appear in the transaction lists.

In relation to FX conversions, I have yet to see it done commercially without fees of some sort. Even if they call them bid-ask spreads or the like, the test is whether you can convert an amount from one currency to another and back again immediately, and expect to get back the original amount in the original currency. Since there are costs involved in facilitating FX conversions, it is normal business for the costs to be passed on to the consumer.

Comment: thank you for your very help full answers, to answer Flux it would be in GDP. Im not trying to buck the system I just find the actual exchange rate the bank uses is considerably higher than the market rate and they than charge a commission fee, So at least if I was paying the forex fee I would get  the saving of market rate and not inflated bank rate.